# How does async task interrupt main thread (from itself - the main one)?

Tags: asynchronous

I can't seem to find this specific implementation detail, or even a pointer to where in an OS book to find this.

Basically, **main** thread calls an async task (to be run later) **on itself**. So... when does it run?

Does it wait for the run loop to finish? Or does it just randomly interrupt the run-loop in the middle of any function?

I understand the registers will be the same (unless separate thread), but not really the instruction pointer and what happens to the stack, if anything does happen.

Thank you

Comment: This is more of a language/toolkit specific question than an OS specific one.

Comment: What's the context of this question? What OS?

Comment: This is more of a c/obj c question, or rather, low-level. Same is true for C++. More of a hardware/register/instruction pointer question. I realize the implementation is OS specific, like exactly when, but I have no idea where the general idea of "which function to interrupt" is findable, since most apps loop continuously. 

"Hey, I'm gonna run in a circle, tell me when to change shoes, but I won't stop", kind of idea... when do I stop running in the circle to change the shoes. (this may have been answered, just responding to questions)

Comment: I'm voting to close this since I may have forgotten this is architecture specific, and nobody answering seemed to realize I said "same thread", I will be more specific in architecture and more generic in thread queue areas, and hope I at least find where to look. But I shall read the unix chapter mentioned also by O Software Guy since he probably pointed the right way.

Answer (score 2):

In C# the task is scheduled to be run on the current `SynchronizationContext`. The context basically has a queue of tasks which it schedules to run on the threads it is associated with, in a GUI app there is only one thread so the task is scheduled to run there.

The GUI thread is not interrupted but it executes the task when it finishes all other tasks preceding it in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

The threads of a process all share the same *address space*, not the same CPU registers.  The thread scheduling is done depends on the programming language and the O/S.  Usually there are explicit scheduling points, such as returning from a system call, blocking awaiting I/O completion, or between p-code instructions for interpreted languages.  Some O/S implemtations reschedule depending on how long a thread has run for time-based scheduling.  Often languages include a function that explicitly offers the CPU to any other thread or process by transferring control to the process or thread scheduler component of the O/S.

The act of switching from one thread or process to another is known as a *context switch* and is carefully tuned code because this is often done thousands of times per second.  This can make the code difficult to follow.

The best explanation of this I've ever seen is [http://www.amazon.com/The-Design-UNIX-Operating-System/dp/0132017997](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132017997) classic.

Comment: Er, I read too fast. This question is for same-thread, not thread-switching. I get the thread-switch part I believe... see my comment in the original spot